# Почему не выполняется метод для удаления записи из таблицы на jsp (база в mysql)?

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate, jsp, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста почему не выполняется метод deleteUser в классе UserController для удаления записи из базы (mysql). При нажатии на ссылку "Delete" в таблице со списком пользователей (list-user.jsp) возвращается эта же страница, но запись остается не удаленной. Никаких ошибок нигде не выходит.

**Все запросы, которые выполняет Hibernate:**

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_, user0_.address as address0_, user0_.birthdate as birthdate0_, user0_.category as category0_, user0_.comment as comment0_, user0_.confirmPassword as confirmP6_0_, user0_.email as email0_, user0_.enabled as enabled0_, user0_.login as login0_, user0_.name as name0_, user0_.password as password0_, user0_.surname as surname0_, user0_.tel as tel0_ from user user0_
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.address as address0_0_, user0_.birthdate as birthdate0_0_, user0_.category as category0_0_, user0_.comment as comment0_0_, user0_.confirmPassword as confirmP6_0_0_, user0_.email as email0_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled0_0_, user0_.login as login0_0_, user0_.name as name0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.surname as surname0_0_, user0_.tel as tel0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_, user0_.address as address0_, user0_.birthdate as birthdate0_, user0_.category as category0_, user0_.comment as comment0_, user0_.confirmPassword as confirmP6_0_, user0_.email as email0_, user0_.enabled as enabled0_, user0_.login as login0_, user0_.name as name0_, user0_.password as password0_, user0_.surname as surname0_, user0_.tel as tel0_ from user user0_
```

**User.java:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc.domain;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Date birthdate;
    private String address;
    private String tel;
    private String email;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String category;
    private String comment;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

**UserDao.java:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc.dao;
import com.springapp.mvc.domain.User;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao {
    public List listUser();
    public void addUser(User user);
    public void removeUser(Long id);
}
```

**UserDaoImpl.java:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.springapp.mvc.domain.User;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User")
                .list();
    }

    public void removeUser(Long id) {
        User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                User.class, id);
        if (null != user) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserService.java:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc.service;
import com.springapp.mvc.domain.User;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {
    public List<User> listUser();
    public void addUser(User user);
    public void removeUser(Long id);
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc.service;

import com.springapp.mvc.domain.User;
import com.springapp.mvc.dao.UserDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return userDao.listUser();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeUser(Long id) {
        userDao.removeUser(id);
    }
}
```

**UserController.java:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc.controller;
import com.springapp.mvc.domain.User;
import com.springapp.mvc.service.UserService;
import com.springapp.mvc.validation.SendEmailValidator;
import com.springapp.mvc.validation.UserValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SendEmailValidator sendEmailValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value="signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("user", new User());
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUsers(Map<String, Object> map) {

        map.put("user", new User());
        map.put("userList", userService.listUser());

        return "list-user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user")
                             User user, BindingResult result) {
        userValidator.validate(user, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        }
        userService.addUser(user);

        return "signup-success";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{userId}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId")
                                Long userId) {
        userService.removeUser(userId);

        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "forgot-password", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sendPassw(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("user", user);
        return "forgot-password";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="forgot-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSendPassw(User user, BindingResult result) {
        sendEmailValidator.validate(user, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "forgot-password";
        }
        return "email-sent";
    }
}
```

**list-user.jsp:**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<html>
<t:template>
<body>
<c:if test="${!empty userList}">
    <table class="user-table">
        <tr><th colspan="9"><span class= "users-label">
            <spring:message code="label.users"/></span></th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th><spring:message code="label.name"/></th>
            <th><spring:message code="label.surname"/></th>
            <th><spring:message code="label.birthdate"/></th>
            <th><spring:message code="label.address"/></th>
            <th><spring:message code="label.tel"/></th>
            <th><spring:message code="label.email"/></th>
            <th><spring:message code="label.login"/></th>
            <%--<th><spring:message code="label.password"/></th>--%>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.surname}</td>
                <td>${user.birthdate}</td>
                <td>${user.address}</td>
                <td>${user.tel}</td>
                <td>${user.email}</td>
                <td>${user.login}</td>
                <%--<td>${user.password}</td>--%>
                <td><a href="delete/${user.id}">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
    </t:template>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено.
После добавления в файл mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml строки:  <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc.controller"/> и в файл с настройками БД database.xml строки:   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc.dao, com.springapp.mvc.service, com.springapp.mvc.validation"/> все заработало.